# explode mysql string for $wpdb->insert

Tags: php, wordpress, explode

I'm trying to explode this string, so it can fit  "$wpdb->insert" function in wordpress.
this is the string to insert. The file contains about 42k strings like this:

```
(601, 'STANDARD', 'Adjuntas', '', 'Colinas Del Gigante, Jard De Adjuntas, Urb San Joaquin', 'PR', 'Adjuntas', 'America/Puerto_Rico', '787,939', '18.16', '-66.72', 'NA', 'US', 0, 0, ''),
```

this is the code

```
if ( file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/install/usa_zip_codes.sql')){
                $filecontent = explode("\n",file_get_contents( realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/install/usa_zip_codes.sql'));
                foreach( $filecontent as $row){
                    $array = array();
                    $array = explode(", ", trim(preg_replace("/[()]/","",$row),","));
                    $wpdb->insert( 
                            $wpmyplugin_table['yp_usa_zip_codes'], 
                            array( 
                                    'zip' => $array[0], 
                                    'type' => trim($array[1],"'"),
                                    'primary_city' => trim($array[2],"'"),
                                    'acceptable_cities' => trim($array[3],"'"),
                                    'unacceptable_cities' => trim($array[4],"'"),
                                    'state' => trim($array[5],"'"),
                                   ....
```

but when i have strings like ***'Colinas Del Gigante, Jard De Adjuntas, Urb San Joaquin'***, it will also split it to array elements. I've tried to explode by `explode(", '",` but this part ***, 0, 0, ''*** wont be split correctly. How do you deal with these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). You should be able to convert

```
(601, 'STANDARD', 'Adjuntas', '', 'Colinas Del Gigante, Jard De Adjuntas, Urb San Joaquin', 'PR', 'Adjuntas', 'America/Puerto_Rico', '787,939', '18.16', '-66.72', 'NA', 'US', 0, 0, ''),
```

Into:

```
601, 'STANDARD', 'Adjuntas', '', 'Colinas Del Gigante, Jard De Adjuntas, Urb San Joaquin', 'PR', 'Adjuntas', 'America/Puerto_Rico', '787,939', '18.16', '-66.72', 'NA', 'US', 0, 0, ''
```

`str_getcsv` can then be used to turn the above string into an array. This will ignore commas inside of values.

Comment: Yes!! this one. it does the trick!!) i've replaced `$array = explode(", ", trim(preg_replace("/[()]/","",$row),","));` to `$array = str_getcsv(trim(preg_replace("/[()]/","",$row),","),',',"'");` and it works now. Thank you, Jim